# Doctrine2 + ZF2: Hydrate entity that has a many-to-many association via join-table with metadata

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, hydration

I have two entities `Rental` and `Item`. `Item`s are associated to `Rental`s via a join table including some metadata, so that the join table effectively becomes a third entity `RentedItem`.

Because a `RentedItem` can be identified by its associated `Rental` and `Item`, it doesn't need its own ID but uses a compound key consisting of those two foreign keys as primary key instead.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Rental
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RentedItem", mappedBy="rental", cascade={"all"})
     * @var ArrayCollection $rented_items
     */
    protected $rented_items;
    // ...
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Item
{
    // ...
    // Note: The Item has no notion of any references to it.
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class RentedItem
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Rental", inversedBy="rented_items")
     * @var Rental $rental
     */
    protected $rental;
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Item")
     * @var Item $item
     */
    protected $item;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     * @var bool $is_returned
     */
    protected $is_returned = false;
    // ...
}
```

A `Rental` can be created or altered via a RESTful API, including some of its related objects. The corresponding controller uses the `DoctrineObject` hydrator of the ZF2 DoctrineModule to hydrate the rental object with the given form data. The new data is passed to the hydrator as an array of the form

```
$data = [
    // We only use the customer's ID to create a reference to an
    // existing customer. Altering or creating a customer via the
    // RestfulRentalController is not possible
    'customer' => 1, 
    'from_date' => '2016-03-09',
    'to_date' => '2016-03-22',
    // Rented items however should be alterable via the RestfulRentalController,
    // because they don't have their own API. Therefore we pass
    // the complete array representation to the hydrator
    'rented_items' => [
        [
            // Again, just as we did with the customer, 
            // only use the referenced item's ID, so that
            // changing an item is not possible
            'item' => 6, 
            'is_returned' => false
            // NOTE: obviously, the full array representation of
            // a rented item would also contain the 'rental' reference,
            // but since this is a new rental, there is no id yet, and
            // the reference should be implicitly clear via the array hirarchy
        ],
        [
            'item' => 42,
            'is_returned' => false
        ]
    ]
];
```

Usually the hydrator sets up the references correctly, even for completely new entities and new relations. However, with this complex association, hydrating the `Rental` fails. The code

```
$hydrator = new \DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject($entity_manager);
$rental = $hydrator->hydrate($data, $rental);
```

fails with the following exception

```
Doctrine\ORM\ORMException

File:

    /vagrant/app/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/ORMException.php:294

Message:

    The identifier rental is missing for a query of Entity\RentedItem
```

Do I have to manually set up the references for the rented items? Or may this be caused by a faulty configuration or something?

Comment: have you tried adding `@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RentedItem", mappedBy="rental", cascade={"persist"})`

Comment: It is actually set to `cascade={"all"}`, but the exception is thrown by `$hydrator->hydrate()`, long before flushing. So I think the cascade option doesn't even affect this problem, or does the hydrator take this setting into account too?